# How to make each particle in particle.js clickable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, particle.js

I want to add some hover functionality / clickable functionality over each particle in particle.js. Is that even possible to do that? If yes please guide me through the process. If no then is there any other alternative to achieve this (using other js libraries or css).

Comment: Particles.js don't expose anything like that, you can try [tsParticles](https://github.com/matteobruni/tsparticles) like in this codepen sample: https://codepen.io/matteobruni/pen/QWyGMxZ?editors=1111

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Caelan. Just one more question can I assign each point to any particular link/URL . If yes can you tell me how to do it?
Thanks in advance !

Comment: It is possible but you need to add particles manually like in this sample: https://codepen.io/matteobruni/pen/GRpYdGv
The returned particle after the `addParticle` can be customized and you can add an url property that you'll retrieve again when clicked